# Calling scala method with a gatling scenario

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a simple function like :

```
object Actions {
    def myAction() {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use this method as a scenario ? Like :

```
val scn = scenario("My scenario").exec(Actions.myAction())
```

This code doesn't compile but I don't understand why.. it seams exec is waiting for a chain / scenario builder (or a validation object).

Thks !

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: overloaded method value exec with alternatives: [... list of alternatives] cannot be applied to (Unit)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exec expects a ChainBuilder, but here, you're returning nothing (Scala deprecated procedure style) because you're missing the `=` sign.

```
object Actions {
    def myAction() = {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```